# What is the list of ingredients for recipe #99?

Tags: fiz

I have found another recipe scrap! This time it is for recipe #99!

[image]

What ingredients do I need and in what order to complete recipe #99?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completing recipe #99 results in learning the **Red Kastle IRA** recipe:

[image]

This consists of the following ingredients:

- East Kent Goldings x2
- Cascade
- Irish Ale Yeast
- Two Row Malt
- Water
- Vienna Malt
- Irish Moss

Comment: what? the description says it's an IRA. am I missing something?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about ;)